# Loss special characters while converting session var to javascript var

Tags: javascript, php

I put an array containing name of cities into a session variable.

Example of array : 
Saint-Tite, QC
Saint-Émile, QC
Sainte-Adèle, QC
Sainte-Agathe-des-Monts, QC

When I converting this session variable array into a javascript array

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['villeDB']) ?>;
```

The array will look like this now :
Saint-Tite, QC
null
null
Sainte-Agathe-des-Monts, QC

How can I keep special characters while converting my array of cities name ?

Comment: try this as well. `var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode(htmlspecialchars("<?php echo $_SESSION['villeDB']; ?>", ENT_QUOTES)) ?>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` requires that strings be encoded in UTF8.

Personally, I like to program in a single-byte character set. It's just so much less of a headache in general. But in this case, I have a helper function:

```
function json_output($json) {
  if( is_array($json))
    array_walk_recursive($json,function(&$a) {if(is_string($a)) $a=utf8_encode($a);});
  elseif( is_string($json))
    $json = utf8_encode($json);
  $j = json_encode($json,true);
  return $j;
}
```